# windows cmd shell environments

Tags: shell, windows-command-prompt

I use it regularly (cmd), but let's be frank, its environment sucks. No tabs, resizing the window is a pain, ... and so on.

[Console2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) and [PowerCmd](http://www.powercmd.com/) fix some of these problems. But still, I'd love to know are there any other environments for cmd shell.
If you know of any, do tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've also heard of [Terminator](http://software.jessies.org/terminator/) and [Poderosa](http://en.poderosa.org/).

Answer (score 7):

Have you looked into [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx)? It doesn't have tabs, and its resizing isn't great, but it's a huge advance over the cmd shell language.

Comment: +1 for PowerShell, especially if you know how to use .Net objects.

Comment: It's not too hard to "roll-your-own" host for powershell if you want to add tabs, etc.  Here's a good book on doing this: http://www.amazon.com/Professional-Windows-PowerShell-Programming-Providers/dp/0470173939

Answer (score 3):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/) is the closest thing I can think of to a full featured shell environment on a windows machine. If you are at all familiar with a *nix environment check out Cygwin.  [PowerShell](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsserver2003/technologies/management/powershell/default.mspx) is also a great option and a drastic improvement of cmd.exe.

Comment: I know of both. But they're different shells, and I'm not able to change those, since I have some command line utils and applications which depend on workings of cmd.exe. Other from that, I think cygwin (or unxutils)'s best thing since toasted bread and marmalade.

Answer (score 0):

If you want unix command shell, install the services for unix and run the unix shell of your choice.  Powershell is probably the best shell I've seen for any OS. powershell v2 will have a full [ISE](http://get-powershell.com/2008/12/18/customizing-graphical-powershellise/). I'd stay away from anything involving cygwin as there are alot of gotchas involved in getting cygwin installed and working (and I've never run into something that cygwin does that can't be done in the unix subsystem)

Comment: I don't like cygwin because it just seems unnatural on a *windows* system, to put it shortly, but I wouldn't say it has problems with installing and working. What did you mean by that ?

Answer (score 0):

Powershell by way of [PoshConsole](http://poshconsole.codeplex.com/):

[alt text http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=PoshConsole&DownloadId=56402](http://i3.codeplex.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=PoshConsole&DownloadId=56402)

Comment: Looks nice, but doesn't answer the question.

Comment: Highest upvoted answer is powershell, and this tops that

Comment: Yes, well, not by me. I cannot stop others from upvoting answers, even if they are unrelevant to the question.